# Android and PHP Creating an API

Tags: php, android, html, http, post

I'm trying to set up a PHP API for my Android application to interact with, my problem is that the post data never seems to get posted and I can never retrieve the response body (HTML/TXT) from the URL given.

My code

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost clientpost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.129/updateMain.php");

                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_id", "1"));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("job_name", "Test"));

                    clientpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(clientpost);

                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

If I can post data then I will be able to post JSON to the server and retrieve JSON from the server, thus overcoming the biggest hurdle I have at the moment.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using Volley library, it is faster and easier.

Comment: I checked volley out, again the response never gets printed... that would be a different question on its own though. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getResponse(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

    url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    String result = "ERROR";
    Log.d("Pair", nameValuePairs.toString());
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams http_params = httpclient.getParams();
    http_params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(http_params, TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(http_params, TIMEOUT);
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = "ERROR";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = "ERROR";
    }

    try {
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = null;
        if (response != null) {
            entity = response.getEntity();
        }
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = "ERROR";
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return result;
}
```

Use this Method with AsyncTask or background thread

Comment: Just prints error, never prints the stack trace. This method all seems very complicated for such a simple task? I'm probably wrong, but it's a lot to take in.

Answer (score 1):

This one is working for me. Please do take care of exceptions ans error handling. Key121 variable is your php file url.

```
  class callServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    loginCheck();
    return null;
    }
} 
public void loginCheck()
{
InputStream is = null;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aa","11"));   
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bb","22"));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string
    try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
    Log.e("log_tag", "----------------"+result);
    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

You need to use stream and buffered reader for analysing response. Do check and let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me, the response never gets logged Log.d("Response", result) never prints anything. Also I did add the catch and am running this in a different thread.

Comment: @JamesParker : Complete class code is updated in answer. Check and let me know your output/error.

Comment: Here I will require your php file too as you say even other methods don't give output.