# How to send url paremeters to php server and get back response to android

Tags: php, android, http, get, url-parameters

I'm trying to create a basic application where I want to send a request from android to php server like this: http://www.eg.com/eg.php?a=blabla:blablabla:bla.

Then when i get this data I want do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['a'])) {

    $a = $_GET['a'];

    $array = explode(':', $a);

    $data1 = $array[0];

    if($data1 == "blabla") {

        Send response to android here.. 
    }
}
```

The problem is that i dont know how to send data to and back from android to php server. I looked at many answers but most send json data or use the depreciated apache http library or does not talk anything about the php server side or are specific to secnario of that person. Please can you give me a very clear answer on how to do this, thanks :)

If there is an answer that already covers this question, please provide my with the url for that answer before voting me down.

Comment: send data eppending to url with ? and name value pair since i could see that you are using only GET method on php, and u could receive via json object and parse it at android end

Comment: Yeh I dont mind using json object but i dont know how to do this on the android side then i dont know how to send back response from php to android and receive that data on android. Can you please show me an example? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226832/android-and-php-creating-an-api  This one helps you to use namevalue pair

Comment: by the way this `$a = isset($_GET['a']);`will not return an array, it's returning a boolean, If you want to explode a boolean, you'll have a problem

Comment: yeh I meant $a = $_GET['a']; but i just copied and pasted the $_GET part from the if statement and forgot to remove the isset part ;)

Comment: @SubinThomas The answer on the link you gave me only sends a request to php.. do you know how to send data back from php and there is no php code so how you would you recieve the data in php in the first place? :) ? (this is probably because i dont understand the code but) .. can you please provide a simple example for both android and php side? :)

Comment: example : http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Comment: whatever you send back as echo json_encode($variable);  will reach back android @edwinj

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271793/connect-android-app-data-with-website-database @edwinj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a simple solution with the help of the comments and hours of research:

You can simple call this method by using this:

```
HashMap<String , String> postDataParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

postDataParams.put("name", "value");

performPostCall("URL", postDataParams);
```

Java code:

```
public String performPostCall(String requestURL,
                                   HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;

                    Log.e("Res:", response);
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

On the php side you can get the data by using:

```
$_POST['name']
```

you can send back response by simply doing this:

```
echo "response here..";
```